# Preserve vertices within a certain distance from another mesh

Tags: python, scripting, vertices, faces

I have two meshes. Mesh A (cube) and Mesh B (monkey). I would like to only retain the vertices of mesh A that are within a certain distance from mesh B using python.
Like in the example picture below, the monkey head and the cube would be right next to each other and I would like to select only the vertices of the cube that are within a certain (small) distance from the monkey head. I moved the monkey head in the image below for illustration purposes and in my situation these two meshes would be right next to each other. From there I would use select inverse and delete the inverse selection in python to only preserve the selected faces/vertices seen in the image below.

The image below is a simplified version for illustration purposes of what the issue is that I am trying to solve. The meshes I am working with are more complex. I am looking forward to any creative solutions or ideas!

[image: Dummy example]

Comment: So the "Cube Object" has a boolean difference on it that has subtracted the "Monkey" object from it and you want to delete everything except the verts that were cut into the Cube from the boolean?

Comment: Yes, I created this example for illustrative purposes. In reality I have two more complex meshes that run partly along each other and I would like to retain only the parts of one of the meshes that are close to the other. Some parts of the mesh (the backside of the cube) are far away from the other mesh (the monkey) and I would like to delete the vertices corresponding to this part that is not touching the monkey face.